# When retrieving from mysql database preview broken

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I'm new to php and mysql and completely stuck here.

I want to do an image upload on my webpage which shows the uploaded image in an image gallery.

The code successfully stores the image in the database but doesn't work when showing the image in the gallery. Instead it just shows a broken thumbnail.

Please help me. I've been working too long on this.

Here is the **index.php**:

```
<form action="addexec.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addroom">
Select Image: <br />
<input type="file" name="image" class="ed"><br />
Caption<br />
<input name="caption" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" id="button1" />
</form>
<br />

// Photo Archive
<br />
<br />
<?php
include('config.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div id="imagelist">';
echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
echo '<p id="caption">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

**and this is the addexec.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" .    
  $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $caption=$_POST['caption'];

        $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (location, caption) VALUES 
  ('$location','$caption')");
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();                 
}
?>
```

Comment: You should really escape data you've put in your db - this is most likely the issue.

Comment: Your code checks out. Running your code from the root of my server and having uploaded files to the photos sub-folder, uploaded correctly and images shown correctly afterwards. Check your paths.

Comment: If you're trying to run your code from another sub-folder, then it will fail.

Comment: do not use the $_FILES["image"]["name"] as the actual name of the file. Although we sensible people use filenames the operating system understands, users do not always do that. Instead, generate a filename that relates to the user and whatever else that is useful to identify the owner later. Use the supplied filename as a caption when displaying the image on the screen

Answer (score 0):

1. Use mysql_real_escape_string() on both *$location* and *$caption*!!!
2. Keep in mind that if you upload a different picture with a name that
   already exists in your db you'll overwrite the old one!
3. Use pdo_mysql or mysqli
4. Check the return value of **move_uploaded_file()**

**Update**

I've run your code on my site. The first file name I've tested had *%20* in it and it failed.

The solution is as simple as adding *urlencode()* around location in index.php, so the line would look like:

```
echo '<p><img src="'.urlencode($row['location']).'"></p>';
```

You might also need to use *htmlentities()* on the next line with *caption*.

Anyway, my notes from above are still important and I'd recommend following those.

Comment: This doesn't address the real problem. Data is successfully entered in DB.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - we still do not know that - $location might have a special character like empty space or "+", etc...

Comment: You may be right. I will test OP's code myself and see.

Comment: OP's code checks out, I didn't change anything. As far as empty spaces and special characters, I doubt it. I entered #1$*x123 in the caption and it worked fine.